# Getting Unknown type "org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator" in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I am trying to implement log4j using netbeans ide.

My Java code is

```
public class MyClass {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
     static {
        File file = new File("log4j.properties");
        System.out.print(file.getAbsolutePath());
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(file.getAbsolutePath()); --- line 5
    }
    }
```

Problem is that code execute successfully without any error but log file is not created. When I put netbeans in debug mode, I am getting following inside watch variable console "Unknown type "org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator".  at line 5 of above code. I am trying to include log4j.properties file inside my WEB-INF/classes folder but it is not get created. I am not sure what the issue is.

```
my log4j.properties file look like 

#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

#Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender   
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/resources/log4j.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


I am getting logs in console but no log4j.log file get created. Any idea?
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the library.

Comment: I changed the log4j.properties file and it worked.